# Error: For loop is not working in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have list of files in a file which I am trying to iterate over the file but for loop is not working. Can you please help me?

Example:

```
list_file.txt

EMAIL_MSG
CALL
TERR
CASE
```

Shell Script:

```
ls -1tr ${incremnt_ec2_path}|awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'  > list_file.txt

    for f in `cat list_file.txt`; 
    do
    Foldername=`echo "$f"`
        echo $Foldername
        aws s3 cp ${bucket}${Daily_Src_Location}/$Foldername  ${archivebucket}/SrcFiles/AMPIL/AMPIL_SRC_${logdate1}/$Foldername/ --recursive --sse >> ${log_out_file}'Lnd_load_valdtn'_${logdate1}.log 2>&1
                

        printf "aws s3 cp ${bucket}${Daily_Src_Location}/$Foldername  ${archivebucket}/SrcFiles/AMPIL/AMPIL_SRC_${logdate1}/$Foldername/ --recursive --sse" >> ${log_out_file}'Lnd_load_valdtn'_${logdate1}.log 2>&1
    done
```

It is showing only `EMAIL_MSG` only and coming out of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work: ?

```
    while read Foldername
    do
        echo $Foldername

        aws s3 cp ${bucket}${Daily_Src_Location}/$Foldername  ${archivebucket}/SrcFiles/AMPIL/AMPIL_SRC_${logdate1}/$Foldername/ --recursive --sse >> ${log_out_file}'Lnd_load_valdtn'_${logdate1}.log 2>&1

        printf "aws s3 cp ${bucket}${Daily_Src_Location}/$Foldername  ${archivebucket}/SrcFiles/AMPIL/AMPIL_SRC_${logdate1}/$Foldername/ --recursive --sse" >> ${log_out_file}'Lnd_load_valdtn'_${logdate1}.log 2>&1
    done < cat list_file.txt
```

I assume you already have the other variables all set properly.. like: `$bucket`, `$Daily_Src_Location`

If this does not work, please add the exact output you are receiving as + errors